# How does windows force log off during removal of smart cards

Tags: windows, authentication, smartcard, smartcard-reader

What does the action 'force logoff' during removal of smard card. Does it just close your programs or does it ask you to close them?

Comment: Ah i found it: https://www.farbeyondcode.com/How-to-lock-Windows-immediately-upon-smart-card-removal-5-2999.html Next Question: What lies behind those commands?

Comment: To be more precise: I need to know the commands behind the logout and the forced logout, etc. Because i wrote an application that uses the smart card you used for logging into windows.

Comment: Please rephrase your question, showing us what you tried, what you expected and what happened. Otherwise you are just asking us to google it for you.

Comment: A user logs into an tomcat based application. During this login his smart card gets read (the same with which he logged into windows). If the user removes the card from the reader, is there a chance to interrupt the windows locking, but at the same time lock the application!? To do this, i need to know the commands behind the locking or the log out. I am just looking for a way to configure these commands independently. That's why i am interested in the commands in the back end.

Comment: Good. But [SO is not a forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Don't ask question in comments. Click on edit under your question, and put that text in there. +Tell us what language you are using and what messages are sent to your application's message loop. These simple rules make this site what it is. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: This is undocumented, so the only sensible thing to say to your product owner is: there's no way to tell for sure, and even if we could, Microsoft might change it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

The "force" in "Force logoff" means what it will happen, and there is nothing you can do about it.

[From MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776917%28v=WS.10%29.aspx):

> If you click Force Logoff in the Properties dialog box for this
>   policy, the user is **automatically logged off** when the smart card is
>   removed.

You can try it yourself in a few easy steps:

1. Open notepad and type "I love StackOverlow". Do not save.
2. Try to logoff from Windows manually
3. You not be forcefully logged off. Notepad will ask you to save your text.
4. Click cancel and don't save your document just yet
5. Remove the smart card

At the end of step 5, you will be forced to log off, no questions asked. Hence the name. The Winlogon process has the last word. It can do what it wants, using whatever API it needs. It is not documented, and does not need to be. There is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Which command is behind this? Is it: "shutdown /f" or "shutdown /l" or "logout" or something different? Do you know where i can look this up? BTW: I have no smart card log in method for windows.

Comment: Why do i ask this? We have no method to check wheter windows ask to close all programs or not. If you tell me it does not ask you, i believe you. The problem is, i got to prove it to my product owner :-). That's why i need to find the underlying internal command.

Comment: Why do you think, that Windows use shutdown.exe??? Your comment have no sense. Yes some APIs are used in both, but dont mix Windows logoff with shutdown command.

Comment: Get a 30$ usb smart card reader and test it in the lab. +If this is not programming related, consider asking on [SU] or [SF].

Comment: So, which command is executed? What do i have to write in the console to simulate the same behavior? Where/Who invokes the internal command?